# Is there a difference between "one declaration per line" and "multiple variable assignments per line" in Java? or how can the behavior be explained?

Tags: java, this, variable-assignment

```
public class ThisKeywordDemo1 {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThisKeywordDemo1 tkd = new ThisKeywordDemo1();
        tkd.getData();
    }

    public void getData(){
        //int a = x = 50;
        //int b = y = 40;

        int x = 50;
        int y = 40;
        int a = 50;
        int b = 40;

        System.out.println(a + b);
        System.out.println(x + y);
        System.out.println(this.x + this.y);

    }
}
```

In the above code snippet the output is 90 90 30, which is expected.

```
        int a = x = 50;
        int b = y = 40;

        //int x = 50;
        //int y = 40;
        //int a = 50;
        //int b = 40;
```

But when commented lines are uncommented and one line declarations are commented the output becomes 90 90 90,
Could any of you explain the behavior ?

Comment: Since you've already defined x and y as class-level variables, your assignments
```
int a = x = 50;
int b = y = 40;
```
reassign the values of x and y to 50 and 40, respectively. To avoid this, name your class-level variables differently from function variables.

I stay away from defining/assigning multiple variables in one line to avoid this sort of confusion and for readability.

Comment: you are confused because, first example uses method's local variables x,y but the second example uses class's data members or class attributes (x,y).

Comment: I agree that multiple variable assignment per single line is confusing and is something to stay clear from. The confusion is with the behavior of "this" keyword. Expectation is that should be able to refer to the instance variable and the answer should always be 90 90 30 irrespective of how the method local variables are declared and initialized.

Comment: On the contrary to my comment above I now know that the entire behavior is related to to variable scopes, variable shadowing and multiple variable assignment in single line. 'this' keyword behaves like we all expect it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two cases

Case: A

```
    int a = x = 50; // int a = this.x = 50;
    int b = y = 40; // int b = this.y = 40;
```

Case: B

```
    int x = 50; // introduce method local x, this.x stays 10
    int y = 40; // introduce method local y, this.y stays 20
    int a = 50;
    int b = 40;
```

So, in the second case you shadow class fields with local variables.

The inline assignment will be like:

```
    int a = 50, x = 50; // int a = 50, int x = 50;
    int b 40, y = 40; // int b = 40, int y = 40;
```

Comment: So in Case: A : int a = x = 50; behaves like int a = this.x = 50;  the application of implicit 'this' happens with the way how the variable assignment is done ? strange enough, in both case A  and case B, IntelliJ shows 10 and 20 respectively when mouse hovered on this.x and this.y but changes  in run time to 10|20 or 40|50 depending on how x and y get declared.

Comment: `int a, x = 50` only assigns 50 to `x`, not to `a`. `a` remains uninitialized. Same for `int b, y = 40`, only `y` is assigned.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, shame on me. Fixed

Comment: @kofemann seems you are spot on, in int a = x = 50; assignment int 'a' get defined and 50 gets assigned but since 'x' is not defined locally at the time It seems 50 gets assigned to the instance variable instead, even though without the use of explicit 'this' keyword. Behavior is not directly related to how the 'this' keyword works but to the scope and shadowing of variables.